# Check my hash contains all parameters rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

Hi want to check that my hash contains all parameters or not e.g

```
product => {name: 'Test Product', sku: 'test_123', price: '' }
```

This is my hash, in this hash price parameter contains empty value so how i gonna check it wither price is empty or not using rails function in one line.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, any parameter could be empty e.g name or sku.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will work for you.

```
product.all? {|k,v| !v.empty?}
```

If there are any value is missing then it will return false.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this by ruby way

```
product.values.all? {|x| !x.blank? }
```

for rails use model validation for that attribute

```
validates :price, presence: true, allow_blank: false
```

Comment: Thanks this is simple way :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I found another simple solution may be this will also help in case if nil is present.

```
product.values.include? "" and product.values.include? nil
```

Thanks